# GOOGLEFINANCE function - specific instrument returning #N/A

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance, stockquotes, google-finance-api

I am trying to use the google finance function within Google Sheets to return the share price for Vital Healthcare Property Trust which is listed on the New Zealand stock exchange.

Here is the instrument in question:

- https://nz.finance.yahoo.com/quote/VHP.NZ/
- https://www.nzx.com/instruments/VHP

For all other instruments on the NZ stock exchange, it just works. For example:

```
=googlefinance("NZE:MEL")
=googlefinance("NZE:GNE")
=googlefinance("NZE:RYM")
```

These all return as expected, but

```
=googlefinance("NZE:VHP")
```

returns `#N/A`.

Out of desperation, I've tried all of the following ticker combinations:

```
VHP
VHP.NZ
VHP.NZE
VHP.NZSE
VHP:NZ
VHP:NZE
VHP:NZSE
NZ.VHP
NZE.VHP
NZSE.VHP
NZ:VHP
NZE:VHP
NZSE:VHP
```

Why does this specific instrument not return a value correctly?

And how do I fix it/work around it?

Comment: Rather than a programming question this looks to be something related to the Google Finance service. Have you considered to ask about this on [quant.se]?

Comment: Your instrument should be available @ [googlefinance](https://finance.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this specific instrument not return a value correctly?

No idea.

> how do I fix it/work around it?

Perhaps:

```
=1*substitute(index(importxml("https://www.nzx.com/instruments/VHP","//h1"),2,),"$","")
```